# Print answer of switch case in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, switch-statement, case

I want to print the answer of switch case to console, how do I go about it?

Example

```
select 
    ID, 
    order by
        Case When Marks >= 76 Then print 'Student' @ID has grade 'A'  
             When Marks >= 65 Then  print 'Student' @ID has grade 'B'
             When Marks < 35 Then  print 'Student' @ID has grade 'C'
        End as grade
From 
    Student
```

Output:

```
Student 1 has grade C
Student 2 has grade B
Student 3 has grade A
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: what do you mean by print, here? can you show sample input and the expected output?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than printing, if you simply want to work out the students grades and display them, then you can calculate their grade in the SELECT statement, like this:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN Marks >= 76 THEN 'Student ' + CAST( ID AS VARCHAR ) + ' has grade A'  
         WHEN Marks >= 65 THEN 'Student ' + CAST( ID AS VARCHAR ) + ' has grade B'
         WHEN Marks < 35  THEN 'Student ' + CAST( ID AS VARCHAR ) + ' has grade C'
    END AS grade
FROM 
    Student
```